# Android: SharedPreferences not getting pulled in another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am currently having some trouble getting a shared preference in another activity. I currently have the following set up in my main activity:
OnCreate method:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tut = preferences.getString("KEY", "");
        ip = tut;
```

Then I have a menu to edit the preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(
                            MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    String value = input.getText().toString();
                    editor.putString("KEY", value);
                    editor.commit();
                    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String tut = preferences.getString("KEY", "");
                    ip = tut;
```

However when I try to receive the data in another activity in its OnCreate method it doesn't get the data:

Second Activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tut = preferences.getString("KEY", "");
        ip = tut;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "getPreferences(0)" you need to set and use shared preferences with his own name, this is an example:

```
//Fragment Activity One
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor setPrefs = prefs.edit();
setPrefs.putString("name",profile.getName());
setPrefs.putString("email",profile.getEmail());
setPrefs.putString("idFacebook",profile.getIdFacebook());
setPrefs.putString("password",profile.getPassword());
setPrefs.putString("bio",profile.getBio());
setPrefs.putInt("id",profile.getId());
setPrefs.commit();

//Fragment Activity Two
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user",0);
String name = prefs.getString("name","")
```

thats how i use SharedPreferences, hope it help

Comment: what is the getActivity?

Comment: when you are in a fragment you need to get the activity to know the context, if you are using Activities you can change "getActivity()" for "this." or even discard it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the private version of shared preferences; how you are using it, the values can only be seen by the originating Activity. You should be using `getSharedPreferences(String, int);` instead. Learn more at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref